# Is there a serious forum/chat (not Q&A like StackExchange) on Economics?

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for a:

- Serious forum/chat (like so many math and physics forums I know in the net)
- Where I may able to chat about economics foundations & hypotheses, theory and empiria, and so on, with people who have some knowledge about it.
- Which is NOT a Q&A forum.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about economics within the scope of this site.

Comment: Oh please... This one is a Q looking for objective, specific and short As, and it is about economics, specifically: the economics community. It satisfies all stackexchange specifications. You may understand that this question is important though, at least to anybody who wants a complementary website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be useful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/decision_theory_forum

Also, in econjobrumors sometimes there are interesting discussions...

Answer (score 0):

As Alvaro said, http://www.econjobrumors.com/ is where economics graduate students and professors mostly congregate to talk.

But be aware that the form there is anonymous and not for the faint of heart.

economics.SE also has a [chat room](https://economics.stackexchange.com/chat) for economics, which is not restricted to Q&A (although it is currently not very active).