# Are there other active online communities about economics?

Tags: reference-request

While waiting to the economics stackexchange to become as active as the mathematics one (and of course, meanwhile participating in it to promote its growth! the stackexchange format really seems to me to be an excellent way to organize discussion), I'm looking to see if there are other active online communities centered around economics as a scientific discipline. Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at these earlier questions and their answers:

[Is there a serious forum/chat (not Q&A like StackExchange) on Economics?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/12763/is-there-a-serious-forum-chat-not-qa-like-stackexchange-on-economics)

[Forums to discuss and learn hot topics of economics research](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/17792/forums-to-discuss-and-learn-hot-topics-of-economics-research)

["EconSpark": The AEA's new forum](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1898/econspark-the-aeas-new-forum)

Comment: Thank you for the resources! My bad for not properly researching this stack, "online economics", "online community", etc. didn't turn up any results so hopefully this title will help out with similar queries!

Comment: EconSpark does not really count as a community, all posts are from a single person.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker what is going on over there?

Comment: Good question, I'm surprised the whole thing still exists. I think they pay someone to moderate...

Comment: @Giskard EconSpark lasted just few months and then it all died, I joined it when it was launched because at university our lecturer promoted it but it died very quickly. It probably died because it was not organic, the early posts seemed all to be forced, people posting just to post something because it is new

Answer (score 3):

:)

You can check out the below mentioned Piazza discussion forum which is primarily for students who wish to pursue or are pursuing Masters/PhD in Economics.

[Discussion Forum](https://piazza.com/demo_login?nid=j9llzujhf0n1c0&auth=d3c50f4)

Answer (score 1):

There is one forum called thegradcafe, and you can easily find it on Google. I'd been its' member for a year, and there was for sure a sub-forum dedicated to economics. It still is there, but I have no idea if it's still active.
Also, there are a few amazing subreddits, where you can have interesting discussions with members.